# The entire content of my Wordpress page has disappeared

Tags: wordpress, content, page

I have a blog installed on my site using Wordpress. Last week I upgraded Wordpress from 2.6 to 3.0.4 (I had to do this manually).

All went well, or so I thought, but I have just noticed that the content of an existing *page* has vanished.  The page URL still works, but all content has disappeared - doctype, html tags, body tags, everything.

Please note, this is specific to **pages** - posts are still displaying fine.

I have since created a brand new page which does not display the content either.

Things I have tried include

- Switching to a freshly installed theme
- Deactivating all plugins
- Setting the problem page to draft, and back again
- Deleting the .htaccess file

I suspect it's a database problem and have contacted my hosting company who have said the only thing they can do is restore the DB from a backup, but that I should consider it a last resort.

Does anyone have any further ideas what to try?

Comment: can you paste your page.php here? it wille help

Comment: What is the url of your blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments - the page is now back up and running, but I am not certain why.

My theory is that I actually fixed it by deleting the .htaccess file which I removed from the root of `/public_html` and assumed would be recreated by Wordpress.

It's not been replaced in the `/public_html` folder, but without me noticing a .htaccess file was created in the `/public_html/blog` folder (where the blog is kept).

As I didn't notice this at first I can't be certain this was the solution, but it is my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. The them is well installed and looks great. But the content on pages and post do not appear when you preview the website. You can only see them in the dash board. Can anyone help?
my website is http://a-1duicounselingservices.com/

Comment: Unless the accepted answer here solves your problem I would suggest asking your question in its own right. Adding it here as an 'answer' in an already answered question means not many people will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue. I upgraded to 3.1.1 and I can see everything in the dashboard but not on the actual pages. The home page is working but none of the other pages work.